# printing support on chrome packaged apps

Tags: google-chrome, printing, google-chrome-extension, package, google-chrome-app

I can't seem to find any example of window.print() support in chrome packaged apps - can someone please post an example?

I'm using this

```
function clickHandler(e) {
  window.print();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

from "Hello World!" sample platform app, but I can't seem to get it working.

is there a special permission settings I should use?

Thanks!

Comment: As a sanity check, is *any* JavaScript working on the page? Could you change your click handler to `console.log("works"); window.print();` just to be sure?

Comment: I guess popups(like `window.print()`) are blocked from chrome extensions, i tried a sample and couldn't resolve!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, window.print() works in Chrome Apps. You can find a sample in the [official samples repo](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/printing).

It is as simple as calling window.print() in any DOM window of your app:

```js
  // prints the content of the current window:
  window.print();

  // prints the content of another AppWindow:
  anotherAppWindow.contentWindow.print()
```

[AppWindow](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#type-AppWindow) is the Chrome Apps object that encapsulates and extends the actual DOM window with app capabilities. This object can be obtained by either:

1. saving the parameter from the callback of `chrome.app.window.create`
2. calling `chrome.app.window.current()` on any code running in the context of the desired window

Comment: I think to make this work, the file has to be chosen by the user explicitly or has to be in a directory that was previously chosen by the user explicitly. Using a file internal to the app (chrome.storage.local) won't work, as the browser won't be able to access that file.

Comment: Yes, thanks for bringing this up. Printing from a Chrome App works perfectly now! There is even a sample: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/printing

Comment: How bout silent printing?

Comment: Currently not possible, @FandiSusanto, unless you communicate directly with the printer using chrome.usb or chrome.sockets APIs, for example.